# Using Environmental Variables in Visual-Studio C# Properties

Tags: c#, visual-studio, settings

I would like to use an **environmental path variable** in the **Visual Studio C# properties pages** to set the "Output path".

`$(MYDIR)` does not work. The Path becomes `C:\....\release\$(MYDIR)`. It works perfectly in the C++ properties page.

Question: How can I use a path variable in the C# properties page.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use SubString() method to extract the path

```css
            string path = @"C:\....\release\$(MYDIR)";
            string root = path.Substring(0, path.LastIndexOf('\\'));
            string folder = path.Substring(path.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1);
```

Comment: Thank you but I need the Environment Variable in the properties pages of the C# project, not within the program itself.